# Has Erdős conjecture on arithmetic progressions been proved?

Tags: number-theory, additive-combinatorics

The [conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_conjecture_on_arithmetic_progressions) states that if $A$ is a set of natural numbers and $$\sum_{n\in A}\frac1n=\infty,$$
then $A$ contains arbitratily long arithmetic progressions.

I wonder has it been proved?

Comment: I edited it so curious people don't need to visit wikipedia if they don't know the conjecture. Anyhow, it is a safe bet that if it had been proved, or even if a credible proof claim had been announced, the wikipedia article would have said so.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen, ok. thank you.

Comment: I've deleted my answer to this post (that the resolution of this conjecture is likely years away), as it is unhelpful.

Answer (score 4):

This is open even in the simplest case of arithmetic progressions of lengths three. The best result in this direction, for three-terms, is due to [T. Bloom](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.5800) building on work of Sanders, and the paper reviews earlier contributions.

You can also see [a recent related MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198387/most-dense-subset-of-numbers-that-avoids-arbitrarily-long-arithmetic-progression) for further references.